# Bootstrap navbar not expanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a collapsible navbar with Bootstrap but no matter how many times I try and how many times I check the way it's done I can't manage to make clicking the button expand the navbar.

This is my HTML:

```
<section id="upper-section">
    <div class="container mini-container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#nav" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="nav" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="prjects.html">Projects</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="professors.html">Professors</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="admin.html">Administration</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</section>
```

And I made sure `jquery` is being loaded before `bootstrap.js`:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I don't know what's wrong, why pressing the button isn't expanding the navbar?

**Edit:** [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rrmjmaby/1/)

Comment: Create a jsfiddle and post the css that you are using.

Comment: Did you find any errors in the Console? (Check by pressing F12)

Comment: @PraveenKumar no errors related to Bootstrap.

Comment: @dabadaba Better create a fiddle to play around.

Comment: I just uploaded a fiddle and you can see it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's missing the data-toggle on your button

```
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav" aria-expanded="false">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here is what I did. I grabbed the 3 js cdn (jquery, popper.js & js) from the boostrap website here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

Put those links in the head section of the html. I have put the bootstrap css cdn below those ones.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Please follow the website link for the latest versions.

Answer (score -1):

You need use a dropdown class in an li element, and a dropdown-menu in a ul element:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Directorio MINSAL</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Exposiciones<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Exposiciones 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Exposiciones 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Asambleas<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Asambleas 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Asambleas 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#">Estudiantes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Maestros</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Formación pedágogica</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Item Activo</a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="/login/final">Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

... And F12. It's very useful in these cases.

Answer (score -1):

Recently, I also faced the same situation and I found that the targeted ID (i.e id="nav") had a space in its name...Just like below

```
<div id="nav " class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
```

So, after removing this extra white space it worked for me.
I know my answer is not related to the posted question...I wrote it if in case any reader may find it useful.